# Using aspose and devexpress mvc dashboard export of excel file error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, export-to-excel, dashboard

I'm using aspose.dll to export an excel file but when I click the button to export it doesn't return an excel file.

In debug, I see that after it goes to `return redirectToAction`, it goes to `application_error` in Global.asax.

How can I fix this? My project was created by devexpress gallery.

[This is my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vcl9c7txo0s4we/Code.png?dl=0)

Comment: Why your controller redirecting to other page when you want to return an Excel file? The file should be available using controller action method which returning `FileResult` instead of `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: With my code with asp.net mvc , it return successfull. But with devexpress, it don't return.

Comment: In which conditions the code goes to `Application_Error` part? Maybe you can debug when calling `Application_Error` method by adding this line `Exception exception = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();` and see what error message stored there.

Comment: There are no error message. But it doesn't return file.